# How to edit PersonalDictionary.zip, can I add words manually using desktop computer and import the file again?

Tags: python, android, swipe, android-glide, gboard

While **adding a word** to the Personal Dictionary in Android it suggests the word while typing on the mobile keypad. While exporting the dictionary it exports to a file **PersonalDictionary.zip** (file's content starts from: # Gboard Dictionary version:1, and further words are given with specific characters between words).

**When I try to edit and import the file, the Gboard does not accepts it.**

Probably, Google checks the date/time of the zipped folder, the file inside (dictionary.txt) and some other parameters, etc.

Anyone who can guide how to edit the file? Actually **I want to add all the words in my Phone-Contacts-Names to the dictionary so that I can search them quickly** using swipe/swype or glide (gesture texting).

This can be found at Settings (Text Settings) -> Dictionary -> Personal dictionary... depending on settings environment. In simple, you can go to Text-Settings by clicking on Settings icon on Keypad.